# Splitting a definite integral doubt

Tags: definite-integrals

Evaluate the integral

$\int_0^{\pi}\frac{x}{a^2*\cos^2(x) + b^2*\sin^2(x)}\; dx$

In my textbook solution the integral has been split into intervals from $0$ to $\pi/4$ and then from $\pi/4$ to $\pi/2$. My question is what is the need to this? Why can't we compute the integral directly with $u=\tan x$ substitution? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: After $\;14\;$ months being a member and $\; 92\;$  questions asked, I think it is about time you learn the easy directions to properly write mahtematics in this site: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Comment: It is actually useful for outside math.stackexchange too. $\LaTeX$ and $\TeX$ are widely used to write math research papers.

Comment: Try to at least see how people changed your previous posts, watch what is between the \$ signs. Look that we changed pi by \pi for instance, see that an integral is just \int_{from}^{to} and that a fraction is just \frac{nominator}{denominator}. Also see that I added a \ before cos and sin, which gave \cos and \sin. This was something that wasn't needed, but sin and cos render more nicely in my opinion when you add \, but this might be personal preference. Watch the difference between $sin$ which is wihtout a \ and $\sin$ which is with a \.

Answer (score 0):

$\tan{x}$ is not continuous on the interval of integration, since $\tan{\frac{1}{2}\pi}$ diverges. Therefore you can't use the [usual substitution rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_single_variable). (Notice the condition that $\varphi$ is continuous: you need to be able to take its derivative.) If you split the interval so that $\varphi$ is single-valued and continuous, then it works.